# How to detect load window in Ionic 2 RC3 Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using several services where I use load of content method. Each of it shows own loadController to show loading window.
How to detect load window is already exists to prevent show new of it?

*Note: I need to detect it in service, but not in component.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this piece of code; I use it for something different, but I guess it may come in handy:

```
import { Nav, Platform, IonicApp, ... } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-custom',
    templateUrl: 'custom.html'
})
export class CustomPage {

    constructor(private platform: Platform,
                private ionicApp: IonicApp) { 

         // ...
    }

    public showModalByClosingPreviousOne(): void {

        let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

        if (activePortal) {

            // Dismiss the active portal
            activePortal.dismiss();
            activePortal.onDidDismiss(() => { 

                // Here you can show the new one...

            });
            return;
        }
    }

    // Or maybe you can just use the `activePortal` property to avoid 
    // showing another loading instead of closing the previous one.
    public showNewModal(): void {

        let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

        if (!activePortal) {

            // Show your modal
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is good. But I need to detect it not in component. I need to detect it in one of my service class. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Your services can inject the ionicapp class aswell and check there.

Comment: @AlexanderZakusilo It's a very bad practice to do things related to the view (like showing a loading) from the service. You should check if you need to show a modal from your component before calling the service. When the service finishes, then you hide the loading window from the component again.

Comment: Sometimes It's only the one way.